# After resizing an encrypted LVM device, the machine takes 4 hours to boot

Tags: debian, lvm, encryption

I have a host, under Debian Wheezy.

The virtualisation software is qemu/KVM, and uses LVM Volumes as disks for the guests.

The guests all have been installed using debian wheezy, full-disk encryption, LVM (/boot is out of the luks device, LVM is divided into /, /home, swap).

Two times I had to resize a drive for a guest, with the wish to grow the /home volume of the guest.

What I did was :

- Turn off the machine
- From the host, grow the guest LVM volume
- From a debian-cd1 boot the guest machine, with rescue/enable=true as an extra boot parameter.
- From that live system, chroot into the guest system (passphrase needed)
- From that chroot, cryptsetup resize
- Still in the chroot, resize filesystem
- update-initramfs

And then I reboot the machine (after correctly unmounted and closed volumes and luks device), and it takes few hours before asking me for the passphrase.

If anybody has ever experienced this or knows about this problem, something I do wrong or so, please let me know!

Here is the dmesg log from last time :

```
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.2.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.2.63-2
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/srvices-root ro single console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200
[    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009dc00 (usable)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 000000000009dc00 - 00000000000a0000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 0000000000100000 - 00000000dfffe000 (usable)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000dfffe000 - 00000000e0000000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000feffc000 - 00000000ff000000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000fffc0000 - 0000000100000000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 0000000100000000 - 00000001a0000000 (usable)
[    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
[    0.000000] SMBIOS 2.4 present.
[    0.000000] DMI: Bochs Bochs, BIOS Bochs 01/01/2007
[    0.000000] e820 update range: 0000000000000000 - 0000000000010000 (usable) ==> (reserved)
[    0.000000] e820 remove range: 00000000000a0000 - 0000000000100000 (usable)
[    0.000000] No AGP bridge found
[    0.000000] last_pfn = 0x1a0000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.000000] MTRR default type: write-back
[    0.000000] MTRR fixed ranges enabled:
[    0.000000]   00000-9FFFF write-back
[    0.000000]   A0000-BFFFF uncachable
[    0.000000]   C0000-FFFFF write-protect
[    0.000000] MTRR variable ranges enabled:
[    0.000000]   0 base 00E0000000 mask FFE0000000 uncachable
[    0.000000]   1 disabled
[    0.000000]   2 disabled
[    0.000000]   3 disabled
[    0.000000]   4 disabled
[    0.000000]   5 disabled
[    0.000000]   6 disabled
[    0.000000]   7 disabled
[    0.000000]   8 disabled
[    0.000000]   9 disabled
[    0.000000] x86 PAT enabled: cpu 0, old 0x7040600070406, new 0x7010600070106
[    0.000000] last_pfn = 0xdfffe max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.000000] found SMP MP-table at [ffff8800000fdad0] fdad0
[    0.000000] initial memory mapped : 0 - 20000000
[    0.000000] Base memory trampoline at [ffff880000098000] 98000 size 20480
[    0.000000] init_memory_mapping: 0000000000000000-00000000dfffe000
[    0.000000]  0000000000 - 00dfe00000 page 2M
[    0.000000]  00dfe00000 - 00dfffe000 page 4k
[    0.000000] kernel direct mapping tables up to dfffe000 @ 1fffa000-20000000
[    0.000000] init_memory_mapping: 0000000100000000-00000001a0000000
[    0.000000]  0100000000 - 01a0000000 page 2M
[    0.000000] kernel direct mapping tables up to 1a0000000 @ dfffa000-dfffe000
[    0.000000] RAMDISK: 369a4000 - 374ca000
[    0.000000] ACPI: RSDP 00000000000fd920 00014 (v00 BOCHS )
[    0.000000] ACPI: RSDT 00000000dfffe550 00038 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCRSDT 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACP 00000000dfffff80 00074 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCFACP 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 00000000dfffe590 01121 (v01   BXPC   BXDSDT 00000001 INTL 20100528)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACS 00000000dfffff40 00040
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 00000000dffffe40 000FF (v01 BOCHS  BXPCSSDT 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: APIC 00000000dffffd50 00080 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCAPIC 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET 00000000dffffd10 00038 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCHPET 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 00000000dffff6c0 00644 (v01   BXPC BXSSDTPC 00000001 INTL 20100528)
[    0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
[    0.000000] No NUMA configuration found
[    0.000000] Faking a node at 0000000000000000-00000001a0000000
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 0000000000000000-00000001a0000000
[    0.000000]   NODE_DATA [000000019fffb000 - 000000019fffffff]
[    0.000000] kvm-clock: Using msrs 4b564d01 and 4b564d00
[    0.000000] kvm-clock: cpu 0, msr 0:16a9701, boot clock
[    0.000000]  [ffffea0000000000-ffffea0005bfffff] PMD -> [ffff880199600000-ffff88019ebfffff] on node 0
[    0.000000] Zone PFN ranges:
[    0.000000]   DMA      0x00000010 -> 0x00001000
[    0.000000]   DMA32    0x00001000 -> 0x00100000
[    0.000000]   Normal   0x00100000 -> 0x001a0000
[    0.000000] Movable zone start PFN for each node
[    0.000000] early_node_map[3] active PFN ranges
[    0.000000]     0: 0x00000010 -> 0x0000009d
[    0.000000]     0: 0x00000100 -> 0x000dfffe
[    0.000000]     0: 0x00100000 -> 0x001a0000
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 1572747
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 56 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 5 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 3920 pages, LIFO batch:0
[    0.000000]   DMA32 zone: 14280 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   DMA32 zone: 899126 pages, LIFO batch:31
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 8960 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 646400 pages, LIFO batch:31
[    0.000000] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0xb008
[    0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] enabled)
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x01] lapic_id[0x01] enabled)
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0xff] dfl dfl lint[0x1])
[    0.000000] ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x02] address[0xfec00000] gsi_base[0])
[    0.000000] IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 2, version 17, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-23
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 5 global_irq 5 high level)
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 10 global_irq 10 high level)
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 11 global_irq 11 high level)
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ0 used by override.
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ2 used by override.
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ5 used by override.
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ9 used by override.
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ10 used by override.
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ11 used by override.
[    0.000000] Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a201 base: 0xfed00000
[    0.000000] SMP: Allowing 2 CPUs, 0 hotplug CPUs
[    0.000000] nr_irqs_gsi: 40
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000000009d000 - 000000000009e000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000000009e000 - 00000000000a0000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000a0000 - 00000000000f0000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000dfffe000 - 00000000e0000000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000e0000000 - 00000000feffc000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000feffc000 - 00000000ff000000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000ff000000 - 00000000fffc0000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000fffc0000 - 0000000100000000
[    0.000000] Allocating PCI resources starting at e0000000 (gap: e0000000:1effc000)
[    0.000000] Booting paravirtualized kernel on KVM
[    0.000000] setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:512 nr_cpumask_bits:512 nr_cpu_ids:2 nr_node_ids:1
[    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 28 pages/cpu @ffff88019fc00000 s82944 r8192 d23552 u1048576
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s82944 r8192 d23552 u1048576 alloc=1*2097152
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 1 
[    0.000000] kvm-clock: cpu 0, msr 1:9fc13701, primary cpu clock
[    0.000000] KVM setup async PF for cpu 0
[    0.000000] kvm-stealtime: cpu 0, msr 19fc0dfc0
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Node order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 1549446
[    0.000000] Policy zone: Normal
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/srvices-root ro single console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.000000] Checking aperture...
[    0.000000] No AGP bridge found
[    0.000000] Calgary: detecting Calgary via BIOS EBDA area
[    0.000000] Calgary: Unable to locate Rio Grande table in EBDA - bailing!
[    0.000000] Memory: 6116684k/6815744k available (3432k kernel code, 524756k absent, 174304k reserved, 3307k data, 580k init)
[    0.000000] Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  RCU dyntick-idle grace-period acceleration is enabled.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:33024 nr_irqs:512 16
[    0.000000] Console: colour VGA+ 80x25
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    0.000000] console [ttyS0] enabled
[    0.000000] hpet clockevent registered
[    0.000000] Detected 3415.532 MHz processor.
[    0.000000] Marking TSC unstable due to TSCs unsynchronized
[    0.008000] Calibrating delay loop (skipped) preset value.. 6831.06 BogoMIPS (lpj=13662128)
[    0.008000] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.008000] Security Framework initialized
[    0.008000] AppArmor: AppArmor disabled by boot time parameter
[    0.008000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 1048576 (order: 11, 8388608 bytes)
[    0.012000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 524288 (order: 10, 4194304 bytes)
[    0.015249] Mount-cache hash table entries: 256
[    0.016170] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.017500] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
[    0.018775] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
[    0.020011] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
[    0.021356] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
[    0.022698] Initializing cgroup subsys blkio
[    0.024016] Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event
[    0.025383] mce: CPU supports 10 MCE banks
[    0.029219] ACPI: Core revision 20110623
[    0.033372] ..TIMER: vector=0x30 apic1=0 pin1=2 apic2=-1 pin2=-1
[    0.035377] CPU0: AMD QEMU Virtual CPU version 1.1.2 stepping 03
[    0.040002] APIC calibration not consistent with PM-Timer: 116ms instead of 100ms
[    0.040002] APIC delta adjusted to PM-Timer: 6249547 (7253497)
[    0.040002] Performance Events: Broken PMU hardware detected, using software events only.
[    0.040002] NMI watchdog disabled (cpu0): hardware events not enabled
[    0.040121] Booting Node   0, Processors  #1 Ok.
[    0.041284] smpboot cpu 1: start_ip = 98000
[    0.053431] NMI watchdog disabled (cpu1): hardware events not enabled
[    0.053428] KVM setup async PF for cpu 1
[    0.053428] kvm-stealtime: cpu 1, msr 19fd0dfc0
[    0.053428] kvm-clock: cpu 1, msr 1:9fd13701, secondary cpu clock
[    0.060005] Brought up 2 CPUs
[    0.068011] Total of 2 processors activated (13662.12 BogoMIPS).
[    0.069677] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.074798] print_constraints: dummy: 
[    0.076177] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.077716] ACPI: bus type pci registered
[    0.079085] PCI: Using configuration type 1 for base access
[    0.080210] mtrr: your CPUs had inconsistent variable MTRR settings
[    0.081863] mtrr: your CPUs had inconsistent MTRRdefType settings
[    0.084006] mtrr: probably your BIOS does not setup all CPUs.
[    0.085652] mtrr: corrected configuration.
[    0.088260] bio: create slab  at 0
[    0.089632] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
[    0.092010] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
[    0.093576] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
[    0.096015] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
[    0.098360] ACPI: EC: Look up EC in DSDT
[    0.100581] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[    0.102354] ACPI: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
[    0.104014] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    0.113888] ACPI: No dock devices found.
[    0.115411] HEST: Table not found.
[    0.116017] PCI: Ignoring host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=use_crs" and report a bug
[    0.118877] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-ff])
[    0.120055] pci_root PNP0A03:00: host bridge window [io  0x0000-0x0cf7] (ignored)
[    0.120057] pci_root PNP0A03:00: host bridge window [io  0x0d00-0xffff] (ignored)
[    0.120059] pci_root PNP0A03:00: host bridge window [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff] (ignored)
[    0.120061] pci_root PNP0A03:00: host bridge window [mem 0xe0000000-0xfebfffff] (ignored)
[    0.120094] pci 0000:00:00.0: [8086:1237] type 0 class 0x000600
[    0.120330] pci 0000:00:01.0: [8086:7000] type 0 class 0x000601
[    0.120657] pci 0000:00:01.1: [8086:7010] type 0 class 0x000101
[    0.122297] pci 0000:00:01.1: reg 20: [io  0xc0a0-0xc0af]
[    0.124442] pci 0000:00:01.2: [8086:7020] type 0 class 0x000c03
[    0.126058] pci 0000:00:01.2: reg 20: [io  0xc040-0xc05f]
[    0.126769] pci 0000:00:01.3: [8086:7113] type 0 class 0x000680
[    0.127047] pci 0000:00:01.3: quirk: [io  0xb000-0xb03f] claimed by PIIX4 ACPI
[    0.128016] pci 0000:00:01.3: quirk: [io  0xb100-0xb10f] claimed by PIIX4 SMB
[    0.129795] pci 0000:00:02.0: [1013:00b8] type 0 class 0x000300
[    0.132504] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 10: [mem 0xfc000000-0xfdffffff pref]
[    0.136052] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 14: [mem 0xfebf0000-0xfebf0fff]
[    0.141073] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 30: [mem 0xfebd0000-0xfebdffff pref]
[    0.141386] pci 0000:00:03.0: [1af4:1000] type 0 class 0x000200
[    0.148589] pci 0000:00:03.0: reg 10: [io  0xc060-0xc07f]
[    0.149632] pci 0000:00:03.0: reg 14: [mem 0xfebf1000-0xfebf1fff]
[    0.156542] pci 0000:00:03.0: reg 30: [mem 0xfebe0000-0xfebeffff pref]
[    0.156956] pci 0000:00:04.0: [1af4:1001] type 0 class 0x000100
[    0.158142] pci 0000:00:04.0: reg 10: [io  0xc000-0xc03f]
[    0.159248] pci 0000:00:04.0: reg 14: [mem 0xfebf2000-0xfebf2fff]
[    0.164887] pci 0000:00:05.0: [1af4:1002] type 0 class 0x0000ff
[    0.165458] pci 0000:00:05.0: reg 10: [io  0xc080-0xc09f]
[    0.169256] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0._PRT]
[    0.169685]  pci0000:00: Unable to request _OSC control (_OSC support mask: 0x1e)
[    0.174231] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 5 *10 11)
[    0.176076] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 5 *10 11)
[    0.180978] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 5 10 *11)
[    0.184072] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 5 10 *11)
[    0.185535] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKS] (IRQs 9) *0
[    0.187291] vgaarb: device added: PCI:0000:00:02.0,decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
[    0.188014] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.188596] vgaarb: bridge control possible 0000:00:02.0
[    0.189569] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
[    0.190306] PCI: pci_cache_line_size set to 64 bytes
[    0.190443] reserve RAM buffer: 000000000009dc00 - 000000000009ffff 
[    0.190448] reserve RAM buffer: 00000000dfffe000 - 00000000dfffffff 
[    0.190645] HPET: 3 timers in total, 0 timers will be used for per-cpu timer
[    0.192034] hpet0: at MMIO 0xfed00000, IRQs 2, 8, 0
[    0.193147] hpet0: 3 comparators, 64-bit 100.000000 MHz counter
[    0.212036] Switching to clocksource kvm-clock
[    0.214927] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.215592] ACPI: bus type pnp registered
[    0.216366] pnp 00:00: [bus 00-ff]
[    0.216369] pnp 00:00: [io  0x0cf8-0x0cff]
[    0.216371] pnp 00:00: [io  0x0000-0x0cf7 window]
[    0.216372] pnp 00:00: [io  0x0d00-0xffff window]
[    0.216374] pnp 00:00: [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff window]
[    0.216376] pnp 00:00: [mem 0xe0000000-0xfebfffff window]
[    0.216426] pnp 00:00: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0a03 (active)
[    0.216440] pnp 00:01: [io  0x0070-0x0071]
[    0.216472] pnp 00:01: [irq 8]
[    0.216473] pnp 00:01: [io  0x0072-0x0077]
[    0.216492] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.216526] pnp 00:02: [io  0x0060]
[    0.216529] pnp 00:02: [io  0x0064]
[    0.216545] pnp 00:02: [irq 1]
[    0.216564] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0303 (active)
[    0.216594] pnp 00:03: [irq 12]
[    0.216613] pnp 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0f13 (active)
[    0.216633] pnp 00:04: [io  0x03f2-0x03f5]
[    0.216635] pnp 00:04: [io  0x03f7]
[    0.216650] pnp 00:04: [irq 6]
[    0.216652] pnp 00:04: [dma 2]
[    0.216683] pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0700 (active)
[    0.216750] pnp 00:05: [io  0x03f8-0x03ff]
[    0.216766] pnp 00:05: [irq 4]
[    0.216784] pnp 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0501 (active)
[    0.216878] pnp 00:06: [mem 0xfed00000-0xfed003ff]
[    0.216906] pnp 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0103 (active)
[    0.217005] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 7 devices
[    0.217730] ACPI: ACPI bus type pnp unregistered
[    0.228506] PCI: max bus depth: 0 pci_try_num: 1
[    0.228515] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 0 [io  0x0000-0xffff]
[    0.228517] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 1 [mem 0x00000000-0xffffffffff]
[    0.228705] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.231459] IP route cache hash table entries: 262144 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes)
[    0.235819] TCP established hash table entries: 524288 (order: 11, 8388608 bytes)
[    0.250779] TCP bind hash table entries: 65536 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes)
[    0.253381] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 524288 bind 65536)
[    0.255193] TCP reno registered
[    0.256172] UDP hash table entries: 4096 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.257857] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 4096 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.259902] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.260861] pci 0000:00:00.0: Limiting direct PCI/PCI transfers
[    0.262056] pci 0000:00:01.0: PIIX3: Enabling Passive Release
[    0.263174] pci 0000:00:01.0: Activating ISA DMA hang workarounds
[    0.273610] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] enabled at IRQ 11
[    0.275164] pci 0000:00:02.0: Boot video device
[    0.275194] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
[    0.275261] Unpacking initramfs...
[    0.477514] Freeing initrd memory: 11416k freed
[    0.482711] PCI-DMA: Using software bounce buffering for IO (SWIOTLB)
[    0.484075] Placing 64MB software IO TLB between ffff8800dbffa000 - ffff8800dfffa000
[    0.485685] software IO TLB at phys 0xdbffa000 - 0xdfffa000
[    0.487886] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
[    0.489023] type=2000 audit(1414446944.488:1): initialized
[    0.507853] HugeTLB registered 2 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.512541] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
[    0.513981] Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.516081] msgmni has been set to 11968
[    0.518658] alg: No test for stdrng (krng)
[    0.522396] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 253)
[    0.525107] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.526139] io scheduler deadline registered
[    0.527797] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
[    0.529671] pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
[    0.547796] pciehp: PCI Express Hot Plug Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    0.549695] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
[    0.551777] acpiphp: Slot [3] registered
[    0.553206] acpiphp: Slot [4] registered
[    0.554527] acpiphp: Slot [5] registered
[    0.555406] acpiphp: Slot [6] registered
[    0.556338] acpiphp: Slot [7] registered
[    0.557273] acpiphp: Slot [8] registered
[    0.558229] acpiphp: Slot [9] registered
[    0.559134] acpiphp: Slot [10] registered
[    0.560029] acpiphp: Slot [11] registered
[    0.560925] acpiphp: Slot [12] registered
[    0.561909] acpiphp: Slot [13] registered
[    0.562938] acpiphp: Slot [14] registered
[    0.564249] acpiphp: Slot [15] registered
[    0.565569] acpiphp: Slot [16] registered
[    0.566820] acpiphp: Slot [17] registered
[    0.568191] acpiphp: Slot [18] registered
[    0.569475] acpiphp: Slot [19] registered
[    0.570820] acpiphp: Slot [20] registered
[    0.572144] acpiphp: Slot [21] registered
[    0.573376] acpiphp: Slot [22] registered
[    0.574658] acpiphp: Slot [23] registered
[    0.575989] acpiphp: Slot [24] registered
[    0.577173] acpiphp: Slot [25] registered
[    0.578425] acpiphp: Slot [26] registered
[    0.579739] acpiphp: Slot [27] registered
[    0.580980] acpiphp: Slot [28] registered
[    0.582278] acpiphp: Slot [29] registered
[    0.583573] acpiphp: Slot [30] registered
[    0.584773] acpiphp: Slot [31] registered
[    0.586223] ERST: Table is not found!
[    0.587312] GHES: HEST is not enabled!
[    0.588856] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    0.629003] serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[    0.658059] 00:05: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[    0.660565] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
[    0.673119] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:KBD,PNP0f13:MOU] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
[    0.677148] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    0.678248] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[    0.679836] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    0.681944] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0
[    0.684831] rtc_cmos 00:01: RTC can wake from S4
[    0.686732] rtc_cmos 00:01: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
[    0.688777] rtc0: alarms up to one day, 114 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
[    0.690651] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    0.691951] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.693583] TCP cubic registered
[    0.694984] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    0.697245] Mobile IPv6
[    0.698222] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    0.709844] Registering the dns_resolver key type
[    0.714300] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
[    0.714348] registered taskstats version 1
[    0.720212] rtc_cmos 00:01: setting system clock to 2014-10-27 21:55:43 UTC (1414446943)
[    0.724133] Initializing network drop monitor service
[    0.726898] Freeing unused kernel memory: 580k freed
[    0.727988] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 6144k
[    0.730894] Freeing unused kernel memory: 648k freed
[    0.734594] Freeing unused kernel memory: 688k freed
[    0.856102] udevd[51]: starting version 175
[    0.882389] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.887544] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] enabled at IRQ 10
[    0.902570] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.902753] virtio-pci 0000:00:03.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.903451] virtio-pci 0000:00:04.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.904180] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] enabled at IRQ 10
[    0.904217] virtio-pci 0000:00:05.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.908345] libata version 3.00 loaded.
[    0.908908] ata_piix 0000:00:01.1: version 2.13
[    0.909051] ata_piix 0000:00:01.1: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.912461] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.916405] scsi0 : ata_piix
[    0.920989] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.923162] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.925064] scsi1 : ata_piix
[    0.926215] ata1: PATA max MWDMA2 cmd 0x1f0 ctl 0x3f6 bmdma 0xc0a0 irq 14
[    0.928003] ata2: PATA max MWDMA2 cmd 0x170 ctl 0x376 bmdma 0xc0a8 irq 15
[    0.930726] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.933881] uhci_hcd 0000:00:01.2: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.933890] uhci_hcd 0000:00:01.2: UHCI Host Controller
[    0.935462] uhci_hcd 0000:00:01.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.937756] uhci_hcd 0000:00:01.2: irq 11, io base 0x0000c040
[    0.939465] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    0.941008] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.942864] usb usb1: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[    0.944217] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 uhci_hcd
[    0.945600] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:01.2
[    0.947218] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.948370] hub 1-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    0.958914] virtio-pci 0000:00:03.0: irq 40 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.958937] virtio-pci 0000:00:03.0: irq 41 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.958954] virtio-pci 0000:00:03.0: irq 42 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.971100] virtio-pci 0000:00:04.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.971120] virtio-pci 0000:00:04.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.971579] FDC 0 is a S82078B
[    0.973380]  vda: vda1 vda2 
[    1.101935] ata2.01: NODEV after polling detection
[    1.102793] ata2.00: ATAPI: QEMU DVD-ROM, 1.1.2, max UDMA/100
[    1.109793] ata2.00: configured for MWDMA2
[    1.115456] scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM            QEMU     QEMU DVD-ROM     1.1. PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.148087] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 4x/4x cd/rw xa/form2 tray
[    1.149401] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    1.151382] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[    1.158778] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 5
[    1.260227] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
[    1.302176] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    1.307903] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.22.0-ioctl (2011-10-19) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    1.456752] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0627, idProduct=0001
[    1.456755] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=5
[    1.456757] usb 1-1: Product: QEMU USB Tablet
[    1.456759] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: QEMU 1.1.2
[    1.456760] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 42
[    1.485089] input: QEMU 1.1.2 QEMU USB Tablet as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input1
[    1.485328] generic-usb 0003:0627:0001.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v0.01 Pointer [QEMU 1.1.2 QEMU USB Tablet] on usb-0000:00:01.2-1/input0
[    1.485378] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.485384] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[ 6308.594031] PM: Starting manual resume from disk
[ 6308.607186] PM: Hibernation image partition 253:2 present
[ 6308.607188] PM: Looking for hibernation image.
[ 6308.607520] PM: Image not found (code -22)
[ 6308.607522] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
[ 6308.684653] EXT4-fs (dm-1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[ 6310.590145] udevd[372]: starting version 175
[ 6310.869309] WARNING! power/level is deprecated; use power/control instead
[ 6310.917370] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
[ 6310.938347] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[ 6311.083046] piix4_smbus 0000:00:01.3: SMBus Host Controller at 0xb100, revision 0
[ 6311.105034] input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input3
[ 6311.523064] Error: Driver 'pcspkr' is already registered, aborting...
[ 6311.779350] input: ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input4
[ 6312.487542] EXT4-fs (dm-1): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[ 6312.775121] EXT4-fs (dm-1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[ 6313.573035] loop: module loaded
[ 6314.543459] Adding 8519676k swap on /dev/mapper/srvices-swap_1.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:8519676k 
[ 6326.584149] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
```

Comment: Whenever I mouse over your included log, my browser crashes. It's obviously a browser bug, but I can't read the log as is. FYI.

Comment: Despite you tried to explain everything, your post is still very unclear. I could ask a question list from you, but unfortunately I don't have time now. Anyways, this problem seems very mystical.

Comment: Addition: 6300 second is fewer as 2 hours and not 4.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it takes longer to boot when you have a large snapshots on VG. Please check with "lvs" that you are not using any snapshots...